# Select all elements that contain two specific classes

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have buttons with multiple classes:

```
<button class="template-1-box template-1 t-premium active-template"></button>
<button class="template-1-box template-2 t-premium"></button>
<button class="template-1-box template-3 t-premium"></button>

<button class="template-2-box template-4 t-premium"></button>
<button class="template-2-box template-5 t-premium"></button>
<button class="template-2-box template-6 t-premium active-template"></button>
```

How do I select specific buttons which contain `template-2-box` and `active-template` class, using jQuery?

Comment: Try with `$(".template-2-box.active-template")` This will only select those elements that has both classes.

Comment: jQuery uses the same selectors as CSS.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I thought I did the same, but mine has a comma between the class names. Can you explain the difference of with and without comma?

Comment: @yobazzinga https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @yobazzinga if you did `$(".template-2-box,active-template")` would mean that it's looking for multiple senarios. so it would return elements that has either `template-2-box` or/and `active-template` class

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen No, your selector misses a dot before `active-template`. The current meaning is different (I know, typo).

Comment: @pavel yes you are right, missed the dot

Answer (score -1):

just like in css

$(".template-2-box.active-template")

should do the work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).